# Choosing values from pandas column with the lowest value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a df from csv that has 2 columns showing the prices of various items. In some cases the price is a single int/float, but other cases it could be a range of spaces seperated int/floats or mixture of int/floats with strings.

example df:

```
  item            prices            
 ------ --------------------------- 
  a      2                          
  b      3.5                        
  c      5                          
  d      0.04                       
  e      1 8 3 4 2                  
  f      0.04 0.04 0.01             
  g      Normal: 4.56Premium: 4.75
```

What I'm looking is a nice pythonic way to get the prices column to display the lowest possible int/float value for every item. e.g.

```
  item   prices  
 ------ -------- 
  a           2  
  b         3.5  
  c           5  
  d        0.04  
  e           1  
  f        0.01  
  g        4.56
```

The only way I could think of solving this problem for items e and f would be to split the value by using `str.split(" ")` and mapping the output to int or float, but this seems like it would be messy as not all values are the same types. And I don't even know how I would get the lowest value for item g.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for get `integer`s or `float`s, convert to floats and get minimal values:

```
df['prices'] = (df['prices'].str.extractall('(\d+\.\d+|\d+)')[0]
                            .astype(float)
                            .groupby(level=0)
                            .min())
print (df)


  item  prices
0    a    2.00
1    b    3.50
2    c    5.00
3    d    0.04
4    e    1.00
5    f    0.01
6    g    4.56
```

Comment: It's working without this part as well `[0].astype(float)`. Can you please tell why did you add that specifically `[0]` part.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan  - sure, it return Series, if use `[0]`, else it return one column `DataFrame`. Here it does not matter.